# MFMailComposerViewController not recognizing URL as link

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios4

MFMailComposerViewController displays a URL in its message body as plain text and not as a tappable link. Is there anyway I can make this happen?

Comment: add ur lines of codes in ur question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set is as HTML with `<a href="link">The link</a>` using [`– setMessageBody:isHTML:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MFMailComposeViewController/setMessageBody%3aisHTML%3a). Plain is as it is called, plain.

Answer (score 1):

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    composer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [composer setMessageBody:message isHTML:YES];
    NSMutableString *body = [NSMutableString string];
    [body appendString:@"<h1>Hello User!</h1>\n"];
    [body appendString:@"<a href=\"http://www.mysite.com/path/to/link\">Click Me!</a>\n"];
    [composer setMessageBody:body isHTML:YES];
```

hope this works for u. happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is possible and you can do it this way:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]; composer.mailComposeDelegate = self; 
[composer setSubject:subject]; 
[composer setMessageBody:message isHTML:YES]; 
//Message is just a NSString with HTML Content and you can have all the HTML Contents in it.
```